# How to set UITableView cell alpha?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have to set the cells alpha to minimum. I try the following code in cell for row, it's not working.
I've also set opaque but it's still not working. Anyone have an idea about this?

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.alpha =0.5;
```

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763635/how-to-make-background-of-uitableviewcell-with-buttons-transparent/3763760#3763760

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try this..

```
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: `contentView` here is main thing